# How to add currency to excel cell using python xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, excel-formula, xlrd

I have a cell which denotes, it is currency value. TO be more specific, US currency ($). I don't want to do string manipulation since formula which depends on this cell will fail.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite simple than I thought. But wasted a few minutes looking for an answer online. Thought It might help someone.

```
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet(0)
    style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    style.num_format_str = '$#,##0.00'
    sheet.write(row, col, value, style)
```

Comment: I know this is your own question, but the question asks about xlrd, not xlwt.